# Returning fields in addition to values specified in solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr

I am wondering if there is a way to return fields in addition to what is already defined in my solrconfig from a query i.e. something like &fl=+otherfield1,+otherfield2. I would still like to return what the default values are from the solrconfig. Is there some sort of syntax that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a default value for a field in the `schema.xml` file.

`<field name="price" type="float" default="0.0" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

Refer [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to have a predefined list of fields in solrconfig.xml and then dynamically to ask for extra fields on top.

You can do this with - semi-documented - [parameter substitution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parameter+Substitution). You define your fl parameter in solrconfig.xlm:

> **fl=id,name,${extra}**

You can even define it as an *invariant*. Then, if you don't define **extra**, you will just get the two fields. But you can pass **extra** with the query:

> **extra=manu,price**

And that will then return all four fields.